# Using art from Expression Design, in Expression Web

Tags: expression-web

I built a round rectangle in Expression Blend, and would like to bring it into Expression Web as a background for my #welcometext  div. I want to be able to position it and then add text over it.
I brought it in with CSS but it's too big, how can I resize it to fit the div?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds more like a job for CSS than an image.  The following website provides a way of automatically generating suitable backgrounds:

http://www.roundedcornr.com/